# Data compression definition

Tags: database, compression, db2

Could anyone explain the term `"Data compression"` in database (`lame words`). Sorry if this question is simple, but it does help me.

I did find the technical definition, but still did not get a right understanding.

Data compression saves space and saves reading times and so on. Does that mean its aggregating data in the table? Please clarify

Comment: It's not aggregating the data so much as it's replacing it with a small token (12 bits), which persists on the disk, in the page cache in RAM, and even in the transaction log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've tagged this post with `db2`, then I'm assuming your asking about compression within the database.  DB2 does dictionary compression – it replaces common strings with shorter tokens on the actual data pages, reducing the size of the table.

Please see: The wikipedia article on [Dictionary Coder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder) for a general discussion on how this algorithm works.

If you're using DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows you can read this [developerWorks article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0605ahuja/) that describes the compression specifically in DB2.  The article is a few years old but it holds true today (even though there have been many enhancements beyond the initial release).